# Does this property imply convergence?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function that satisfies the property that for some fixed $b$, if $a < b$, then $a < f(a) < b$.

Does this imply that the sequence $a, f(a), f(f(a)), f(f(f(a))), ...$ converges at $b$ for all $a < b$? If not, what extra conditions on $f$ would make it so?

Comment: From the conditions it is clear that the sequence is increasing as well as bounded above. Hence it converges to a fixed limit which is less than or equal to $b$. Note that continuity of $f$ is not needed.

Comment: And the limit can well be strictly less that $b$.

Comment: What I mean is, if that limit is strictly less than $b$, what properties does that function have, and what property, if $f$ had it, would make is so that the limit had to be $b$?

Comment: @GitGud: No, but I was misthinking in another way.  $@$JoeZ: Thank you, but I wasn't thinking about the problem correctly and deleted my comment.

Comment: Okay, I'll delete mine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**.

Denote $a_0=a$ and $a_{n}=f(a_{n-1})$ for every $n\ge 1$. The sequence $(a_n)$ is increasing and bounded from above by $b$. Then $c:=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists and $c\le b$. Since $f$ is continuous, 
$$f(c)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=c,$$
which implies $c=b$ (because otherwise, $c<b\Rightarrow f(c)>c$).

Comment: Oh wait, continuity. Yeah, I think that would do it.

Comment: @JoeZ.: I think you got it now. :)

Comment: I edited my question back into its original form since you answered it without all the extra qualifications I put in. Mind if I adjust your answer a little to remove the extraneous explanation?

Comment: @JoeZ.: OK, I have done. By the way, to recover an earlier version of your post, you can simply view the edit history and click "rollback".

Comment: I was thinking about that, but didn't know how, since I've never actually done that before.